# Dell Inspiron 14 5420 + Kubuntu 23.04 = Web camera not working

Tags: kubuntu, dell, webcam

- It worked a bit.
- And then stopped working.
- And then after some updates it worked again.
- And then it stopped working again.

Some CLIs outputs :

```
➜  ~ sudo lshw -c multimedia
  *-usb:2                   
       description: Video
       product: Integrated_Webcam_FHD: Integrat
       vendor: CN07W56Y8LG0029KBB3RA00
       physical id: 6
       bus info: usb@1:6
       logical name: input23
       logical name: /dev/input/event17
       version: 14.11
       capabilities: usb-2.01 usb
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       logical name: card0
       logical name: /dev/snd/controlC0
       logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D0
       logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D2
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D31p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D4p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D5p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D6c
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D7c
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl latency=64
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:169 memory:601d190000-601d193fff memory:601d000000-601d0fffff
```

```
➜  ~ glxinfo | grep render
direct rendering: Yes
    GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, GLX_MESA_swap_control, 
    GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, GLX_MESA_swap_control, 
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) Graphics (ADL GT2)
    GL_ARB_compute_variable_group_size, GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, 
    GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, GL_INTEL_blackhole_render, 
    GL_NV_compute_shader_derivatives, GL_NV_conditional_render, 
    GL_ARB_compute_variable_group_size, GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, 
    GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, GL_INTEL_blackhole_render, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_copy_image, GL_NV_depth_clamp, 
    GL_EXT_read_format_bgra, GL_EXT_render_snorm, GL_EXT_robustness, 
    GL_EXT_unpack_subimage, GL_INTEL_blackhole_render, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_draw_buffers, GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments, 
    GL_OES_element_index_uint, GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap,
```

Comment: Dell's download page has drivers for every device in your computer for Windows and Ubuntu, but the webcam driver is nowhere to be found, even for Windows. Note that the fact that the device is listed does not mean that the driver is installed and/or working. Do you also have Windows installed?

Comment: Hey @MartinOscarCaballero . Nope. no windows here.